# Necessary to validate _id in Meteor collections?

Tags: validation, collections, meteor

I'm using `Collection.allow(options.insert)` to validate the documents the users inserts into the collection. What I wonder is which validation tests I need to use on the `_id` property of the inserted `doc` (I use random strings as id, not the Mongo-style objectId).

Do I need to check that `_id` is a string looking like an id, or does the database refuse the document if the `_id` property is invalid? Should I also make sure that no other document in the database has that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking you do not need to do any validation tests of the _id.  The database will refuse the insert if the _id you give is not unique but I think that is the only rule.  Checking that the _id is unique could also be picked up afterwards if the insert errors.

Other checks are optional and are just to allow users to access, insert, or remove the documents you want them to.